# Andengine Sprites in array and touched which one?

Tags: android, sprite, andengine, touch-event

I have 10 picture on scene as sprites.And they are in an array.The pictures(sprites) are moving on scene by MoveModifier.
I want this: When I touch any picture,the picture which is I touched should be invisible.
my codes doesn't work because of 19. line(circles[i].setVisible(false);)
eclipse says me do i(variable) as final.I can't do that because i should change it's index of array.What can I do?

```
    final int totalCircleNumber=10;
    int circleNumber=0;
    private Sprite[] circles = new Sprite[totalCircleNumber];
    private Runnable mStartCircle = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        int i=circleNumber++;
        Scene scene = Level1Activity.this.mEngine.getScene();
        float startX = randomNumber.nextFloat()*(CAMERA_WIDTH);
        float startY = -64.0f;
        float finishX= randomNumber.nextFloat()*(CAMERA_WIDTH);
        float finishY= CAMERA_HEIGHT+64.0f;
        int j= randomNumber.nextInt(50);
        circles[i] = new Sprite(startX, startY, textRegCircle[j]){
            @Override
            public boolean onAreaTouched(final TouchEvent pAreaTouchEvent,final float pTouchAreaLocalX, final float pTouchAreaLocalY) {

                if(pAreaTouchEvent.isActionDown())
                {                                       
                     circles[i].setVisible(false);

                }                   
                return true;
                }
        };


        scene.registerTouchArea(circles[i]);


        circles[i].registerEntityModifier(
                (IEntityModifier) new SequenceEntityModifier (
                            new MoveModifier(velocityOfCircle, circles[i].getX(),  finishX, 
                                    circles[i].getY(), finishY)));

        scene.getLastChild().attachChild(circles[i]);
        if (circleNumber < totalCircleNumber){
            mHandler.postDelayed(mStartCircle,second);
        }
    }
 };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace:

```
circles[i].setVisible(false);
```

with

```
this.setVisible(false);
```